# Why User.IsInRole() always return false in ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.0

I have ASP.NET MVC4 application project. I also added WebApi to my project by creating `ApiController`. The case is that in `Controller` descendants both statements returns `true`, but in `ApiController` descendants first statement is `false`, but second returns `true`:

```
bool booool1 = User.IsInRole("Radiolog");
bool booool2 = Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Radiolog");
```

Here is my web.config configuration:

```
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    ...
        <roleManager cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true">
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="RisSystem.Services.CustomRoleProvider" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>
        ...
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>
```

I also noticed that in ApiController `[Authorize]` is working well but `[Authorize(Roles="")]` never let to invoke methods.
In `ApiController` methods I am authenticating with: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new BasicAuthenticationHeaderValue(login, password);` and `FormsAuthentication` in standard `Controller`.

Authentication for WebApi is set in `WebApiConfig.cs` in `Register(HttpConfiguration config)` function:

```
        var authConfig = new AuthenticationConfiguration();
        authConfig.AddBasicAuthentication((userName, password) => AuthenticationService.ValidateUser(userName, password));
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthenticationHandler(authConfig));
```